# How to show that the minimal field between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I would like to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest field between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, if there is a field $\mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{R}$, then it must also be that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{F}$.

My proof is by contradiction, assume that it is not the case $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{F}$. Then, it is possible to find a $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y \notin \mathbb{F}$. Suppose that $y \in \mathbb{Q}$, then, by definition of rational numbers, we may find a $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $d \neq 0$ such that $y=\frac{c}{d}$.

BUT, we know from the assumption above that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{F}$. This means that there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $a=c$ and $b=d$. Furthermore, because $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{F}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$. Now, due to the multiplicative inverse properties of $\mathbb{F}$, we know that $\frac{a}{b}$ exists and that $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{F}$.

Putting it all together, we have that:

$$
y= \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{F}. 
$$

But, this contradicts the assumed that $y \notin \mathbb{F}$.

I am not sure if the above proof works, because in a proof by contradiction, I normally contradict something in the assumption area. However, it seems here that I am contradicting the negated result.

In other words, if I let $P$ be the statement: **"if there is a field $\mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{R}$"**

and $Q$ be the statement **"then it must also be that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{F}$"**,

then in a direct proof I normally have $P \implies Q$. In a contradiction proof, what I understand is that we assume NOT $Q$, then try to contradict something in $P$. But here, it seems I am not really contradicting anything in $P$, but rather something in $Q$, and so seems almost circular.

Could anyone help me see what is missing? Thanks!

Comment: This property is not about the real numbers. Any field, that contains the integers, has the property, that $\mathbb Q$ is the smalles subfield. You should read about the term 'prime field'.

Comment: @MooS This depends on what "is" $\Bbb Q$. For any countable set disjoint from $\Bbb Z$ might define a field structure on $F:=\Bbb Z\cup A$ via a bijection $\Bbb Q\to F$ that is the identity on $\Bbb Z$. Then $F$ is a field that contains $\Bbb Z$, but may not have $\Bbb Q$ as smallest subfield.

Comment: Look up the definition of "ring of fractions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be pretty straightforward.

Let $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb F$ be a field.  Then $\{a*(1/b)|a\in \mathbb Z; b \in \mathbb Z; b \ne 0\}\subset \mathbb F$.  But  $\{a*(1/b)|a\in \mathbb Z; b \in \mathbb Z; b \ne 0\}= \mathbb Q$.  So $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb F$.

That's it.  Nothing more needs to be done.

Your proof by contradiction is fine.  But you prove the contradiction by proving the statement *directly* to get the contradiction.  That is not *circular*; it is redundant.

Try to follow this reasoning:  We are asked to prove $4n$ is even.  We chose to do a contradiction.  So we assume $4n$ is odd.  So $4n = 2*(2n) = 2k$ for $k = 2n$.  So $4n$ is even.  This contradicts that $4n$ is odd.  So $4n$ is not odd. Therefore it is even.

Note: that is not circular.  But it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction is because you are assuming that $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{F}$. If you assume NOT Q you check NOT P: $\mathbb{Q}\not\subset\mathbb{F}\Rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\not\subset\mathbb{F}$.